# cookie value is undefined (react-cookie 2.0.6)

Tags: javascript, cookie, reactjs

Проблема с реализацией react cookie версии 2 и выше. Для запуска сайта я использую webpack-dev-server.
Вот что выводит консоль:

Warning: Failed context type: The context `cookies` is marked as required in `withCookies(App)`, but its value is `undefined`.
          in withCookies(App)
          in Provider

/App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CookiesProvider, withCookies, Cookies} from 'react-cookie'
import {Route, Switch, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

//import RequireAuth from './RequireAuth';
import NotFoundPage from './NotFoundPage';
import LandingPage from './LandindPage';
import WorkSpace from './WorkSpace';
import ActivationPage from './ActivationPage';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CookiesProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
            <Route path="/workspace" component={WorkSpace}/>
            <Route exact path="/activation" component={ActivationPage}/>
            <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </CookiesProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default withCookies(App);
```

/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './components/App';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с версии 2, разработчики вынесли функции типа cookies.set(), cookies.get() в отдельную библиотеку universal-cookie, которую я сейчас и использую. А react-cookie с её CookieProvider, как я понял, используется в основном для изоморфных приложений при формировании страницы на стороне сервера.

Answer (score -1):

в `index.js` оберни `<App />` в `<CookiesProvider>`

```
<Provider store = {store}>
  <CookiesProvider>
    <App/>
  </CookiesProvider>
</Provider>
```

Да и ты в принципе пока нигде с `cookie` не работаешь.